Upgraded to 24.04.1 - dotnet core is installed but won't build, why?
I just upgraded to 24.04.1 and I noticed it removed a lot of packages (old versions of dotnet core 6,7).
I do have dotnet core 8.x installed and it runs and allows me to list the sdks and runtimes.

8.0.110 [/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.10 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.10
[/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

However, when I attempt to build a simple .net core webapi I get the following error:

error NU1101: Unable to find package
Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.ubuntu.24.04-x64. No packages exist with
this id in source(s): nuget.org

What does this mean?  How do I resolve this?

When I searched the web I only found an inconclusive answer for .NET Core 6.x.  But luckily someone had posted to that thread more recently in relation to 24.04.1 and .NET Core 8.x
I was lucky and found the answer at:
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/40676#issuecomment-2102017357
Uninstall & Install Again
The answer is to uninstall (properly) using the following command (mentioned at the prev link):
sudo apt-get remove 'dotnet*' 'aspnet*' 'netstandard*'

Then go back and install .net core again.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu-install?pivots=os-linux-ubuntu-2404&tabs=dotnet8 for those steps.
This resovles my issue.
